# Symposium vs Conference?

Tags: meaning

I am unable get a clear idea about the difference between a `conference` and a `symposium`. The folllowing are the meanings of symposium and conference from www.dictionary.com. As we can see below there is no significant difference between these two. I am not getting `clarity` in the difference from either the below definitions or Google search. I have attended both `conferences` and `symposiums` in my field, but unable to find any difference. Could someone provide me a clear-cut difference between these two (atleast theoretically)?

> **Symposium**:
>   a meeting or conference for the discussion of some subject, especially a meeting at which several speakers talk on or discuss a topic before an audience.
>
> **Conference**:
>       a meeting for consultation or discussion: a conference between a student and his adviser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the OALD for definitions, a [symposium](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/symposium) is:

> a meeting at which experts have discussions about a particular subject; a small conference

A [conference](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/conference) is:

> 1. a large official meeting, usually lasting for a few days, at which people with the same work or interests come together to discuss their views
> 2. a meeting at which people have formal discussions

A *symposium* is usually used to describe a small conference on a single subject. For example, a series of lectures on a single day might be called a symposium.

A *conference* is usually large, possibly taking up many rooms in a hotel or a convention center. It usually takes up several days. It can also describe a single, small meeting--for example,

> He was in conference with his lawyers all day.

Comment: @kkp: OALD usually includes many examples of usage for different words, so I find it helpful even as a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

A symposium is usually a whole day or even two-day affair including scholarly talks, dramatic rendering of poetry, musical interludes, and creative dance expressions--all evolving from a common theme. Recently, the genre of film has been added to a symposium.

A conference is the more conventional day-long meeting of scholars to deliver their research papers to a larger audience.

Answer (score 1):

A symposium is a bit like an academic conference involving scholars and researchers to present their findings.

A symposium can also be quite large in scale — one that I attended took a week and required hiring a multi-storied convention centre with many rooms because there are many sessions.

IMO — In a symposium there is a more narrowly defined topic for each session, and speakers make presentations of their work uninterrupted with questions asked later. A conference in its general sense could be people sharing their opinions alternately at the same time.

You will find that often *symposium* is preferable to the word *conference* in many scientific and engineering, i.e. technical settings.